# Jquery radio button preventDefault on click event, if ajax fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, preventdefault

I have radio buttons. **Ajax** request executed on click and returns response. `success` variable receives result(`true` or `false`). What I need is to make **radio** checked only if **ajax** is successfull. But it marked checked before ajax is called.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function (e){
    var success = callAjax();
    if (!success)
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

Upd.

The reason to use preventDefault is to leave previous radio button checked. Not just uncheck current.

Comment: Update the answer please check...

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).prop("checked",false);` to check the radio button when ajax is return true.

Following code may help you..

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function (e){
    var success = callAjax();;
    if (!success){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

For Live Demo Please Check the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ww5P/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function (e){
    var success = callAjax();
    if (!success){
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

All AJAX requests are run asynchronously, it means that you will not get a response right after your AJAX request is executed.

You would need to change your code a bit to make it work:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function (e){
    var _this = this;
    var currentState = $(this).prop("checked");
    callAjax(function(success) {
        if (!success)
             $(_this).prop("checked", !currentState);
    });
});
```

And you should change your `callAjax` method to receive a callback function as parameter and call then request is complete with `success` parameter.

I hope you got an idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can check/uncheck your checkbox using:

```
$("#chkBox").attr('checked', false); //uncheck 
$("#chkBox").attr('checked', true); //check
```